# How to setup PHP version per project / workspace in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

I have multiple PHP projects and some are in PHP 7.4 and others are in PHP 8.0.

Is there a way to setup the PHP version per project / workspace ?

[Not that it helps much but machine is a Linux Mint 20 box and Visual Studio Code 1.55.1]

Comment: Look at `launch.json` i think that file is workspace specific

Comment: @RiggsFolly Knew about that but could not find the proper settings....

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Visual Studio Code does not support this kind of configuration. So you can not setup the PHP executable per project or workspace.

The only IDE (tried Visual Code, Netbeans and PHPStorm) that I found to support this kind of feature was PHPStorm.